# My R script is being killed with not errors

Tags: r

I wrote and tested this R script in RStudio on my own laptop and it worked with no problems.

```
PS22_compounds <- read.csv("./PS22_compounds.tsv", sep = "\t")
PS22_ECFP4 <- read.csv("./PS22_ECFP4.csv")

tenPer <- nrow(PS22_compounds) * 0.1
tenPer_num <- round(tenPer, digits = 0)
tenPer_sample <- sample(PS22_compounds$compound_chembl_id, size = tenPer_num)

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 0))
cols <- c("id1", "id2", "Similarity", "KS Distance")
colnames(df) <- cols

for (i in tenPer_sample) {
  sim_df <- PS22_ECFP4[PS22_ECFP4$id1 == i,]
  dist1 <- sim_df[ , 3]
  for (k in 1:nrow(sim_df)) {
    sim <- sim_df[k , 3]
    sim_r <- floor(sim * 100) / 100
    comp2 <- sim_df[k, 2]
    comp2_df <- PS22_ECFP4[PS22_ECFP4$id1==comp2,]
    dist2 <- comp2_df[ , 3]
    if (length(dist1) > 1 & length(dist2) > 1) {
      ks <- ks.test(dist1, dist2)
      df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c(i, comp2, sim_r, ks$statistic)
    }
  }
}

write.csv(df, "./Metrics.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I then transferred the script to a server I use, and tried to run it through the terminal on a file which is 850GB big.

```
R CMD BATCH scriptName.r
```

It runs for a while and then it stops, outputting a scriptName.Rout file which says the following (I personally do not see an error besides that warning which should not be enough to kill the process)

```
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

During startup - Warning message:
Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
> PS22_compounds <- read.csv("PS22_compounds.tsv", sep = "\t")
> PS22_ECFP4 <- read.csv("PS22_ECFP4.csv")
```

Does anyone have any suggestions at what could go be going wrong?  Btw, the server has around 1TB RAM.

Comment: Could it be a pathing issue?

Comment: I'd guess the system is killing the process before R can report the problem.  Do you have `ulimit` set to limit your process on Linux?  I don't know what other ways there are to prevent a runaway process from taking the whole system down.

Comment: Thanks both for the suggestions! The thing is that I am not root in the server, so I guess both of what you said need to be reported to the maintainer for possible modifications?

Comment: core file size (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size(kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority(-e) 0
file size(blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals(-i) 4125012
max locked memory(kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size(kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files(-n) 1024
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues(bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority (-r) 0
stack size(kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time(seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes (-u) 4096
virtual memory(kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks (-x) unlimited

This is what unlimited -a returned @user2554330